# is it possible to read an empty csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

Seems odd, but for some condition I need to import an empty csv file, as an `empty` pandas `dataframe`.

When I try that I get the following error:

`EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

How to handle it?

Comment: You can catch the `EmptyDataError` exception and create empty `dataframe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel

You could use try/except.

```
import pandas as pd

try:
      
  df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
except pd.io.common.EmptyDataError:
  print('File is empty')
else:
  print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to achieve what you want is to simply catch the `EmptyDataError` raised by `pandas.read_csv`. Then, you can handle the situation as you see fit (by creating an empty `DataFrame`, for example):

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_csv("empty.csv")
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
```